# SQL: How to find duplicates in pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find records with the same client numbers and end dates according to Qualifier_id column. Qualifier_ID 1 and 4, 2  and 5, 3 and 6 are pairs. 
I want to get the follow result:

```
>     ID Client NO. Qualifier_ID    End Date    R
>     1   10475       1           12/31/9998    1
>     2   10475       4           12/31/9998    2
>     3   10475       2           12/31/9998    1
>     4   10475       5           12/31/9998    2
>     5   10475       3           12/31/9998    1
>     6   10475       6           12/31/9998    2
```

I wrote the SQL below, but it does not work:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Client No],QUALIFIER_ID ORDER BY [Client No]) R
FROM Table 
WHERE [END DATE]='9998-12-31 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: It appears that you are using SQL Server. Can you verify this and add the appropriate tag for the DB you are using?

Comment: Can you add the sixth line of data to match your paragraph? According to this, 2, 5, and 3 are a pair (same Client number and end date), and your `R` column would be inaccurate in your expected results. If anything, you are missing the `End Date` from your `PARTITION BY`.

Comment: Are you from the future? Do they finally invent Skynet?. Why the query doesnt work? We need source data, current and desire output.

Comment: Also, what format are you looking for in your results? You mention a CTE, but there is no CTE here. Do you want the results to be `Qualifier_ID` values delimited by commas to be consumed by an external application? Or do you want to maintain the `OVER` clause for other partitioning logic within the DB (e.g., `COUNT`ing the number of instances within each group)?

Comment: `CLT_NBR`  doesn't exists on your table.

Comment: @Ice: How do you *know* that the pairs are such? There's not enough data presented to discern duplicates across these rows; i.e. there currently isn't enough information to decide how to pair them together. Or, are you saying that 1 and 4; 2 and 5; 3 and 6 are **always** paired together?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

You state that you

> want to find records with the same client numbers and end dates

But you partition by client number and qualifier ID (not end date).

I would start by changing your `PARTITION BY` to:

```
PARTITION BY [Client No.], [End Date]
```

It sounds like you *just know* that 1 and 4; 2 and 5; 3 and 6 are always paired together. You can build a map that gives these qualifiers a group number, join to it, and then include it in the `PARTITION BY`.

For example:

```
WITH MagicGroupings (QualifierId, GroupNumber) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 3

)
,TestData(ID, ClientNo, Qualifier_ID, EndDate) AS
(
    SELECT 1, '10475', 1, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '10475', 4, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '10475', 2, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '10475', 5, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '10475', 3, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, '10475', 6, '12/31/9998'
)
SELECT 
    td.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ClientNo], [EndDate], mg.[GroupNumber] ORDER BY ClientNo) R
FROM 
    TestData td
JOIN
    MagicGroupings mg
    ON
    td.Qualifier_ID = mg.QualifierId
WHERE 
    [EndDate] = '12/31/9998'
```

Would give you:

```
ID          ClientNo Qualifier_ID EndDate    R
----------- -------- ------------ ---------- --------------------
2           10475    4            12/31/9998 1
1           10475    1            12/31/9998 2
4           10475    5            12/31/9998 1
3           10475    2            12/31/9998 2
6           10475    6            12/31/9998 1
5           10475    3            12/31/9998 2
```

BTW, you could eliminate the first CTE by supplying the values in the JOIN:

```
WITH TestData(ID, ClientNo, Qualifier_ID, EndDate) AS
(
    SELECT 1, '10475', 1, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '10475', 4, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '10475', 2, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, '10475', 5, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, '10475', 3, '12/31/9998' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, '10475', 6, '12/31/9998'
)
SELECT 
    td.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ClientNo], [EndDate], mg.[GroupNumber] ORDER BY ClientNo) R
FROM 
    TestData td
JOIN
    (VALUES (1, 1), (4, 1), (2, 2), (5, 2), (3, 3), (6, 3)) mg(QualifierId, GroupNumber)
    ON
    td.Qualifier_ID = mg.QualifierId
WHERE 
    [EndDate] = '12/31/9998'
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I have updated the question. Your SQl did not consider the qualifier ID in Pair.

Comment: @Ice: I took another try at understanding your question and updated my answer. Please clarify further if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need an `order by Qualifier_ID` in for the calculation of `r`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Client No]
                          ORDER BY Qualifier_ID
                        ) as r
FROM Table t
WHERE [END DATE] = '9998-12-31';
```

You might want to include `[END DATE]` in the `PARTITION BY`, but because you are filtering down to a single date, that is not a requirement.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I have updated the question. Your SQl did not consider the qualifier ID in Pair.